# Is there a way to make VSCode not run a c++ program if it's compilation failed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compilation, vscode-tasks

In VSCode, Run and Debug launch task for C++ will run the program regardless of whether or not the compilation succeeded (given that an old executable is still present). I have tried to make a workaround by making the build task depend on the rm task, which would delete the old executable, ensuring that compilation error would not let the program run, but this comes with its own drawbacks, like say **removing a file without an extension if it is accidentally run**. I was wondering if there is some sort of smarter way to do this without making even more hacky solutions like making a custom script that will only run the whole ordeal if the file has an extension (which would still leave plenty of bugs to be found I'm sure)?

For reference, I use g++ for compilation.

Comment: I am unsure how exactly you are removing the executable. Personally, I use makefiles where you can define a "script" for when you want to remove things. For example, every time I compile I remove the old executable and then compile. If you want to you can then try to run the file after compilation has succeeded as well. Would something like that look like the solution you are looking for?

Comment: I am removing the executable using "rm ${filedirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}" using a task, which is supposed to remove the previous executable before the new build